# How to call parent window function in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome

HI,
I've surprisingly found problems, in Chrome browser, in calling window parent javascript functions.
If I have a window with a javascript function defined in it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dolink() {
   . . .
  }
</script>
```

and I have an **iframe** inside that window that makes this call using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
      $('a.arglink').click(function() {
         window.parent.dolink($(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
      });
 });
</script>
```

the call to **dolink** function doesn't work. Stepping with chrome javascript debugger, it appears that window.parent.dolink is *undefined*. It's by design or a mistake that I made? 
In Firefox and IE it works fine.

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the parent document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found it!

It seems that Chrome browser doesn't permit to reference a parent window accessing pages with the **file:** protocol. In fact I tested above code with files on my machine, so with a url like `file:///C:/mytests/mypage.html` . If I put that page in a Web Server, it all works as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue with chrome, but no file protocol is used, it's pure http

Comment: just tested it, that doesn't work :C // I want my upvote back

Answer (score 4):

you should call code like that

```
if(function != undefined)
{
 $(function() {
      $('a.arglink').click(function() {
         window.parent.dolink($(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
      });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `frameElement` and `ownerDocument`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
      $('a.arglink').click(function() {
         window.frameElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow.dolink($(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
      });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just simply did this and it works for me

in iframe

```
function sendToParent() {
    parent.doSomething(); 
}
sendToParent();
```

in parent

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('did it!')
}
```