# Calling a function in parent file from child frame?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a function that resizes the `col` width ratio of my `frameset` in "frame.html":

```
<frameset id="set" cols="*,*" FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=3 BORDERCOLOR=#eeeeee>
    <frame src="index.html">
    <frame src="index2.html"> 
    <noframes></noframes> 
</frameset>
```

The function works fine when called from "frame.html", However i want to call said function from the child file "index.html"... the function needs to remain in the parent file in order to run properly... How can I call my function in `frame.html` from `index.html`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try `parent.functionName()` it should work.

**Edit**

---

Just to be sure that the scope is correct you should probably call `window.parent.functionName()` instead to be sure that it is actually the frames parent that is referenced

**Edit 2**

---

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550858/how-to-call-parent-window-function-in-chrome-browser/2590296#2590296) it seems to handle the same chrome issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: nevermind, Chrome doesn't permit reference to the "file://" protocol, after uploading to my webserver, everything worked fine... thanks