# Call parent javascript function from child frameset's javascript

Tags: javascript, frameset

I am using frameset in my page. In the frameset i have taken two frames and in the first frame i have written some javascript code. How the javascript function of the frame will call the javascript function of the main page.

Can anyone please help :)

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615141/calling-a-function-in-parent-file-from-child-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it :

```
parent.FrameName.FunctionName()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your frames are set up like this:

```
<frameset rows="50, 50">
    <frame src="menu.html" name="menu">
    <frame src="main.html" name="main">
</frameset>
```

Then you can access functions in the frame named `main` from the frame named `menu` using `top.main.functionName()`.

`parent.main.functionName()` will also work in this case, but if you have more nested levels of frames then I find it less confusing to reference `top` (which is always the topmost frame) and 'drill down'.