# Set height for iframe when content has expanded items

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 iframes:

1. navigation
2. dynamic content

I'm resizing content using JavaScript:

```
function autoResize(id) {
    var newheight;
    newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + 'px';
};
```

The html is:

```
<iframe src="navigation.jsp" id="leftFrame" name="leftFrame" onload="autoResize('leftFrame');" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="200" style="height: 100%;"></iframe>
<iframe src="" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" onload="autoResize('mainFrame');" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="200" style="height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

My dynamic pages have some expandable content, but when I'm clicking to expand content page hide its content. (scrollbar="no" for mainFrame )

I don't want to enable scrollbar for main frame because it shows two scrollbars (i.e. mainframe & browser scrollbar) What should i do to fix it?

Comment: don't use iframes, use divs and jquery instead

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [jQuery's load() feature](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of iframes...

```
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nav').load('path/to/navigation');
        $('#content').load('path/to/dynamic content');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Example added. Not 100% production-ready but enough to get you started.

Comment: $.load() added content but not like iframe does, it present data as it is, i just try .load(), but content scattered on page...

Comment: Of course it would - you're loading the HTML into a different page, and HTML on its own *should* have no styling applied. If you want to import styles from another page, you'd need to check it for any linked stylesheets (or embedded styles), and append those to the `<head>` of the current page. That's outside the scope of this question though.

Answer (score 0):

`autoResize` only runs once, when the frame is loaded (as would jQuery's load()). You need to resize the frame every time the frame's content changes. That means [trapping the resize event in the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) and [calling `autoResize` on the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615141/calling-a-function-in-parent-file-from-child-frame) from there.

Comment: Can u please give us a suitable example like where to use window.onresize = function(event) { }