# Javascript settimeout doesn't close the popup

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I'm using this function to open a popup and close it after 3 seconds. The popup opens successfully, but, the settimeout function doesn't works and eventually doesn't close the opened popup.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popUp(id,entry,escape)
  {
popupWindow = window.open('process_concur.php?id='+id+'&entry='+entry+'&escape='+escape,'Concur','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=250,height=250');
      popupWindow.focus();
      setTimeout(function () { popupWindow.close();}, 3000);
  }

//reload the current window when the popup is closed.
     function popUpClosed() {
         window.location.reload();
      }
  </script>
```

The popup page which opens (Code)

```
<?php
include 'classes/class.user.php';
$userMain = new user();
//get parameters
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$entry = isset($_GET['entry']) ? $_GET['entry'] : '';
$escape = isset($_GET['escape']) ? $_GET['escape'] : '';
//now, $escape is sha1 and $entry is base64 encoded..decode entry and check if sha1 of decoded entry matches escape
$dentry = base64_decode($entry);
if(sha1($dentry)==$escape)
{
    //process concur
    if($userMain->reviewExists($id))
    {
        if($userMain->increaseConcur($id))
        {
            echo "Done";
            exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //review doesnt no exist
        echo "Some problems occured at id doesn't exist";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Some problems occured dentry";
}
?>

<script>
window.onunload = function() {
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        window.opener.popUpClosed();
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you use a jQuery modal ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga How is that related to the question?

Comment: Where is `popUpClosed()` called ?

Comment: "settimeout function doesn't work" What does that mean? What have you tried to debug that code? Any `console.log` are displayed?

Comment: @feeela it was a suggestion as pop-ups are, in most situations, blocked by browsers and what he wants can be achieved with a modal.

Comment: i would use a more predictable way to close the window - something like `postMessage`

Comment: It looks correct. Do you get a console error? If you run into an uncaught exception somewhere else in the script before the timeout function runs, js *will* stop execution.

Comment: @edi9999 `popUpClosed()` is called from the popup.

Comment: @user3605847 you can't call one function from one window into the other

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sA4Mm/ — works for me. Whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by the code in the question.

Comment: @user3605847 The popup contents is of no use for the initial problem. If there is a related question, please post it as a separate question…

Comment: @edi9999 — Yes, you can.

Comment: @Quentin How can one call a JS function from one window in another window? That would be a serious security problem…

Comment: @feeela ... it is very much possible.

Comment: @feeela — It would only be a security problem if the windows were on different origins (which they are not, since the URL in the question is a relative one). There are security measures in place to prevent accessing most functions and other properties across origin, those measures do not apply when the origins are the same.

Comment: In the particular case of children windows, you can execute functions of the parent window. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550858/how-to-call-parent-window-function-in-chrome-browser

Comment: @Quentin
Do you want me to post the full code?

Comment: @user3605847 — You should provide a reduced test cause that provides the minimum necessary code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Ensure nothing else is interfering with the process.

Also, the `popUpClosed()` function should be invoked after the window is sent the close signal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function popUp(id,entry,escape)
{
 var popupWindow = window.open('process_concur.php?id='+id+'&entry='+entry+'&escape='+escape,'Concur','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=250,height=250');
 popupWindow.focus();
 setTimeout(function () { popupWindow.close(); popUpClosed();}, 3000);
}

//reload the current window when the popup is closed.
function popUpClosed() {
   window.location.reload();
}

popUp();
</script>
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is not an answer. If you can't reproduce a problem, then vote to close it, don't post answers saying that it should just work. The rest of this is commentary about best practices, not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Your solution made the work worse. Now the window keeps on opening and getting closed without even called.

Comment: @user3605847 - Please understand the code you are pasting.  The last line `popUp()` will cause the popup window to appear. Remove this and call the function from your own code.

Comment: @Kami
Just tried. Did not help, the popup doesn't seems to be getting closed.